# See ASP.Net Performce: PageWeight and Time to load?

Tags: asp.net-3.5

I have a Ajax Postback on my site and the same values get back via PageMethods.
I want to see the PageWeight / what exactly is get back, how I can do this?

The author of this blog have a nice tool: 
http://encosia.com/2007/07/11/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) with FireFox.

The firebug also lists you the page size along with the time taken under the console tab.To do that you need to enable the Net Panel in the firebug.

Bing for firebug and you will see a lot of tutorials on how to do it.

You can also try this tool [Deep Tracing of Internet Explorer](http://ejohn.org/blog/deep-tracing-of-internet-explorer/).It looks nice and seems to have a lot of options for profiling your pages.